# Change multiple inheritance into deriving from a template

Tags: c#, c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Say I have a bunch of code for all controls, yet I need subclasses that interact with my software suite to use those common methods. I really want my subclass to derive from the control, not the class with the common code. (A MyEdit should derive from Edit, not from MyControl). Also, the suite interacts with controls using an interface which MyControl derives from. In order to do this in C++, I would use multi-inheritance like so

```
class MyEdit : public Edit, public MyControl;
class MyControl : public IControl;
```

However, I suddenly discover that I shouldn't use multi-inheritance if I want some controls to be C# which doesn't support multi-inhertiance.
So I thought I could do this...

```
class MyEdit : public MyControl<Edit>;
template class MyControl<Type> : public IControl;
```

Convert the common control stuff into a template, and give it the type of control I want to derive from.

However I'm not sure this will work, because the template templatizes Edit, but it doesn't necessarily create one does it? When I create the template will I actually be able to create the Edit?

And secondly, if this is possible, is it possible in C#? What would it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I quite followed your question, but in regards to:

> However I'm not sure this will work,
>   because the template templatizes Edit,
>   but it doesn't necessarily create one
>   does it? When I create the template
>   will I actually be able to create the
>   Edit?

I would go for

```
template<class Controlled_t>
class MyControl : public Controlled_t, public IControl
{
 //My Control inherits from its templated class
}
```

so that 
`MyControl<Edit>` inherits `Edit`  (which is created) and the interface

Answer (score 0):

In C#, a class can only inherit from one other class, but it can implement multiple Interfaces, so if you want a class that can override behavior for more than one polymorphic type at runtime, you have to use Interfaces. The drawback of Interfaces is that they have no properties or base method implementations, so you may have to duplicate some of the methods in classes that implement the same Interface.

Another, C#-y way to get polymorphic runtime behavior is by attaching delegates. A lot of times I've found that what looks like a multiple-inheritance situation is better expressed as a multicast-delegate situation.

Comment: Delegate is what I've been referred to many times. However, in my situation I'll have a need to have a polymorphic interface into the control from control base, which has common code, and then the implementation of MyControl overrides whatever it needs.

Comment: IMO delegate seems to be getting around the point of single inheritance. And C# doesn't address situations where you want common control to be in a common place. It makes sense for most objects, but doesn't make sense for window's controls

Comment: Yeah, sometimes multiple inheritance is best. If you've already considered and rejected Delegates, then probably the only thing to do is implement multiple Interfaces. You'll probably end up copy-pasting implementations of some of the Interface methods. I don't know of any way around that.